# Installing Authen::Simple::PAM module with cpan in ubuntu fails

Tags: drivers, perl, cpan

I'm trying to install the Authen::Simple::PAM module using cpan from ubuntu terminal and i get an error as shown below (note other modules install perfectly)

```
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
checking for gcc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for pam header files in... no
configure: error: cannot find the pam_appl.h file
Error in configuring the Authen::PAM module.   
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
NIKIP/Authen-PAM-0.16.tar.gz
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Running make test
Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a CPAN package is also [available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libauthen-simple-pam-perl) in the Ubuntu repositories, I'd install the Ubuntu version instead, especially if you encounter build issues:

```
sudo apt-get install libauthen-simple-pam-perl
```

Note that both CPAN and Ubuntu versions are the same (0.2).

Comment: Does this mean by including the module in a perl script will work as usual?? i.e use Authen::Simple::PAM

Comment: Yes, it will be installed system-wide in a location known from the perl interpreter. It will work as usual.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it does work perfect and also no include problems encountered Thanks Sylvain